# Can I make a Spatial Point from lat long with sf package

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I have some lat long data. To set CRS, I used sf package, but I need "SpatialPoints" data for analyses. How can I make a "SpatialPoint"?

```
library(sp)
long <- c(133.2982, 132.6715,133.2375,133.3048,133.2594,133.2165)
lat <- c(35.5716,35.3551,35.5504,35.5707,35.5680,35.5708)
lonlat <-data.frame(cbind(long,lat))

lonlat_sf = st_as_sf(lonlat, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs="EPSG:4326")

is(lonlat_sf, "SpatialPoints")

FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `sf` for the crs, instead you can use `sp::CRS`. From the `SpatialPoints` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.4-5/topics/SpatialPoints) to create an object with class `SpatialPoints` you can use

```
spts <- SpatialPoints(lonlat, proj4string = CRS("EPSG:4326"))

is(spts, "SpatialPoints")

#------
[1] TRUE
```